# Can non-psionic classes use the Autohypnosis skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, psionics

The [**Autohypnosis**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/skills/autohypnosis-wis-trained-only) skill was added by *Ultimate Psionics*, published by Dreamscarred Press*.

On [this page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/skills) it says:

> Presented are new psionics-related skills and existing skills that are used in new ways by psionic characters.

So the skill is *psionics-related* but does that mean it cannot be used by non-psionic classes? I could easily think of fluff related reasons for why/how other types of characters would/could train their mind in such a way. It doesn't seem to require any sort of innate psionic power, like actual telekinesis or other psionic abilities. Just intensive training.

In other words, is it a house-ruling to allow other types of characters to rank in Autohypnosis?

As an allegory, there's nothing preventing a Fighter from having ranks in Spellcraft and/or Use Magic Device...

---

*: So therefore 3rd Party material and not published/supported by Paizo.

Comment: Context: the autohypnosis skill also existed in the 3.5 psionic rules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If no restriction is listed (and I can confirm that none is), no restriction exists. It’s *related* to psionics because the only classes that have it in-class are psionic classes, but others can use it just fine. As you say, there’s no reason it *should* be restricted, and lo and behold, it’s not.

Answer (score 15):

As the author of Ultimate Psionics, I can verify that anyone can use Autohypnosis, but only the psionic classes tend to have it as a class skill. So go ahead!